# How to make an onclick keyboard for a game

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I am building a Hangman game using vanilla javascript, html and css. I have an onscreen keyboard, made in HTML. I am needing to make it so that when you click or press a key, it logs the letter pressed to the screen. I have tried giving each key an onclick event, but that has not worked so far.

Any suggestions are welcome. I am also needing suggestions for the Javascript part.

Comment: Post the code... Nobody can tell you what's wrong without it.

Answer (score 0):

how about an array of your letters,  use the javascript map function to build your buttons for each letter. then loop through and add an event handler to log the value of the button click.

run snippet below

```js
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
const content = letters.map(x => `<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary letter-button" value="${x}">${x}</button>`);
const div = document.getElementById('buttonGroup')
const output = document.getElementById('output');
div.innerHTML += content;

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("letter-button"))
  .forEach((e) => e.addEventListener('click', () => output.innerHTML += e.value));
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example" id="buttonGroup">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=row>
    <span class="badge badge-secondary" id="output"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```